# Recursive search for string within files on a drive

Tags: powershell

I am trying to do a search for specific file within a directory with the following command:

```
gci -recurse -path "E:\" | select-string "searchContent" | select path
```

doing so gave me an insufficient memory error. I have seen other posts recommending piping it into foreach-object, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to work in my scenario. Any assistance appreciated!

Comment: You can narrow down the number of files being passed through the pipeline, i.e.: if you know at least the extension of the file you're looking for you should use `-Filter *.extension`, you should also use the `-File` argument so you are only pipping files to `Select-String`. All this would reduce the amount of used memory. In addition to what's mentioned before, you might wan't to read the files with something that would consume less memory than `Select-String` for example `[System.IO.StreamReader]`.

Comment: Unfortunately, what I am trying to achieve is search for all files unconditionally within a directly recursively for a specific string/keyword..

Comment: I don't see how that would happen.  Are you saving the output to a variable?  This is at least ps 5.1?

Comment: Output doesn't need to be in a variable. I will eventually want them in a file.
The end goal is to list all files in a specific directory that contains the search string.

Comment: update: Thanks for everyone's input. Most suggestion work when testing in a smaller environment. But run into insufficient memory issues when trying to execute it on a larger NAS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When reading the file as a whole (single multiline string), your seach can be much faster than by testing line-by-line.

Also, you could speed up significantly if you could use a filename pattern as filter for the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet. If you for instance only want to search through `.txt` files, add `-Filter '*.txt'`.
In any case, append switch `-File` so Get-ChildItem won't try to pass DirectoryInfo objects to the rest of the code.

Try:

```
# since we use regular expression operator `-match`, escape the word or phrase you need to find
$searchContent = [regex]::Escape('whateveryouarelookingfor')
$result = Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\' -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    if ((Get-Content -Path $_.FullName -Raw) -match $searchContent) { $_.FullName }
}
```

A bit faster than using `ForEach-Object{..}` would be to use a `foreach()` instead (skipping processing time needed to pipe results)

```
# since we use regular expression operator `-match`, escape the word or phrase you need to find
$searchContent = [regex]::Escape('whateveryouarelookingfor')
$result = foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path 'E:\' -Recurse -File)) {
    if ((Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw) -match $searchContent) { $file.FullName }
}
```

Now you can display the full path and filenames on screen

```
$result
```

and save it as text file on disk

```
$result | Set-Content -Path ('X:\FilesContaining_{0}.txt' -f $searchContent)
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly in a test environment. Unfortunately I am still running into memory memory issues when trying to run it on a much larger NAS.

Comment: @TheNaiveITguy In case the sheer number of files gets you into memory problems, the first option, using `ForEach-Object` should prevent that as it is only processing one file at a time through the pipeline, while the second option first gathers all files found in memory making it a lot faster, but is also more memory consuming.. How large are the files you're dealing with?

Answer (score 0):

Just assign it to a variable, and then have a foreach loop that assigns each one to another variable.

```
$files = gci -recurse -path "E:\"

foreach ($fileName in $files)
{
 if ($fileName.Name -like "*searchContent*")
 {
      write-host $fileName.Name
 }
}
```

Comment: OP's code makes me think he is actually looking for a key word in the contents of a specific file not looking for a file name.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am trying to search for content within files.

Answer (score 0):

I feel this should consume less memory. Can't tell for sure but you can let me know. The concept is the same but using [`[System.IO.StreamReader]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader?view=net-6.0).

**Note:** This will keep on looking for **all** files it can find, if you need the loop to stop at first finding then a new condition should be added.

```
foreach($file in Get-ChildItem -Recurse -path "E:\" -File)
{
    $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($file.FullName)
    while(-not $reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        if($reader.ReadLine() -match 'searchContent')
        {
            $file.FullName
            break
        }
    }
    $reader.Dispose()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly in a test environment. Unfortunately I am still running into memory memory issues when trying to run it on a much larger NAS.